# HTML Google log in for Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am having trouble getting the google log in function to work for my website. I am using Firebase as my database and followed the steps they provided there, but it isn't working for me. The main issue is getting the button to call the function with the google authentication code. Here is my code:[image]

[image]

I'm new to HTML so if anyone could help me out that would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have `#demo` element? Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: @Justinas im coding through WordPress so i dont see any errors

Comment: Yes, you see. Right click > Inspect element; F12 or via menu. Than check console tab